# Plotting an image of a discrete dynamical system

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, difference-equations

I am trying to plot a discrete dynamical system of the form
$$\vec{x}_{k+1} = A \vec{x}_k$$
where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix in the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers.
It has an initial value in the form $$\begin{pmatrix}e \\f\end{pmatrix}$$

I would like to create a plot similar to that in:
[Creating an image of a discrete dynamical system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120332/creating-an-image-of-a-discrete-dynamical-system)
But am at a loss to get the function plotted as I have tried both `VectorPlot` and `ListPlot` with little success.
Any advice would be much appreciated :-)

The exact problem I am working on is:
$$\begin{align*} &\vec{x}_k = \begin{pmatrix}2ba-a-b&ba-a-b\\2(a+b-ab)&2(a+b)-ab\end{pmatrix}\vec{x},&\vec{x}_0 = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1/3\end{pmatrix}. \end{align*}$$
I am looking at the plots created by different values for $a$ and $b$ such as $1$ and $1/2$.

I tried the following:

```
a = 1; b = 1/2;
A = {{2*b*a-a-b,b*a-a-b},{2(a+b-a*b),2(a+b)-ab}};
x0 = {1, 1/3};
pts = NestList[A.# &, x0, 15];
ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: More details please! Give us values for a,b,c,d,e,f. Show us the attempts you’ve made with VectorPlot and ListPlot.

Comment: You'd do well to look up `MatrixPower[]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the sliders to modify matrix entries. Click and drag locators (small disks)  to modify initial points; ALT+Click to add/remove locators.

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Transpose @ NestList[#.{{a, b}, {c, d}} &, pt, 100],
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], PlotRange -> 5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[{0., .05, 0.}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Defer /@ pt, LegendLabel -> "{x0,y0}", 
      LegendFunction -> Panel], Right], 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], 
        {ColorData[97]@#, Point@pt[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[pt]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True] /. Line -> Arrow,
 Spacer[10], Spacer[10], Spacer[10], 
 Grid[{{Item[Labeled[Control@{{a, .8, Style["a", 18]}, 0, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[a], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic @ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][a])], 
    Item[Labeled[Control@{{b, .0, Style["b", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[b], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic @ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][b])]}, 
    {Item[Labeled[Control@{{c, .0, Style["c", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[c], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic@ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][c])], 
    Item[Labeled[Control@{{d, .4, Style["d", 18]}, 0, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[d], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic@ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][d])]}}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {15, 15}, Dividers -> All],
 {{pt, 3 {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}}}, Locator, 
    Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> {1, 10}}, 
 Alignment -> Center, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

An alternative implementation using `Graphics`:

```
Manipulate[Legended[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], ColorData[97]@#, 
    Arrowheads[.03], Point @ pt[[#]], 
    Arrow[Partition[NestList[{{a, b}, {c, d}}.# &, pt[[#]], t - 1], 2, 1]]} & /@ 
     Range[Length[pt]], 
   ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> 5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
  Placed[LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ pt], Defer /@ pt, 
    LegendLabel -> "{x0,y0}", LegendFunction -> Panel], Right]],
 Spacer[10], Spacer[10], Spacer[10], 
 Grid[{{Item[Labeled[Control @ {{a, .8, Style["a", 18]}, 0, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[a], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic @ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][a])], 
    Item[Labeled[Control @ {{b, .0, Style["b", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
         ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[b], 20], Top], 
       Background -> (Dynamic @ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][b])]},
    {Item[Labeled[Control @ {{c, .0, Style["c", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
         ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[c], 20], Top], 
       Background -> (Dynamic @ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][c])], 
    Item[Labeled[Control @ {{d, .4, Style["d", 18]}, 0, 1, Slider, 
         ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[d], 20], Top], 
       Background -> (Dynamic @ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][d])]}}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {16, 16}, Dividers -> All],
  {{pt, 3 {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}}}, Locator, 
     Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> {1, 10}},
  Spacer[10],
  {{t, 1}, 1, 80, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False, DisplayAllSteps -> True}, 
 Alignment -> Center, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

**Update:** Modification of the second method for the example in OP's update:

ClearAll[a, b, aA, x0]
aA[a_, b_] := {{2 a b - a - b, a b - a - b}, {2 (a + b - a b),
2 ( a + b) - a b}}
x0 = {1, 1/3};

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], ColorData[97]@1, Arrowheads[.03], 
   Point@x0, 
   Arrow[Partition[NestList[aA[a, b].# &, x0, t - 1], 2, 1]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All], Spacer[10], Spacer[10], Spacer[10], 
 Grid[{{Item[Labeled[Control@{{a, 1, Style["a", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[a], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic@ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][a])], 
    Item[Labeled[Control@{{b, .5, Style["b", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[b], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic@ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][b])]}}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {16, 16}, Dividers -> All], 
 Spacer[10], 
 {{t, 1}, 1, 15, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False, DisplayAllSteps -> True}, 
 Alignment -> Center, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

If you want to control the starting point with a `Locator`:

```
Manipulate[Labeled[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], ColorData[97]@#, 
      Arrowheads[.03], Point@pt[[#]], 
      Arrow[Partition[NestList[aA[a, b].# &, pt[[#]], t - 1], 2, 1]]} & /@ 
        Range[Length[pt]], ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1], 
  Dynamic[pt[[1]]], Top], Spacer[10], Spacer[10], Spacer[10], 
 Grid[{{Item[Labeled[Control@{{a, 1, Style["a", 18]}, 0, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[a], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic@ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][a])], 
    Item[Labeled[Control@{{b, .5, Style["b", 18]}, -1, 1, Slider, 
        ImageSize -> Small}, Style[Dynamic[b], 20], Top], 
     Background -> (Dynamic@ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][b])]}}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {16, 16}, Dividers -> All], 
  {{pt, {x0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None,  LocatorAutoCreate -> False}, 
 Spacer[10], 
 {{t, 1}, 1, 15, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False, DisplayAllSteps -> True}, 
  Alignment -> Center, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting code. The problem I am working on is the following $$\begin{align*} &\vec{x}_k = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}2ba-a-b&ba-a-b\\2(a+b-ab)&2(a+b)-ab\end{array} \right) \vec{x},&\vec{x}_0 = \left( \begin{array}{c}2\\1/3\end{array} \right). \end{align*}$$ Where I will be inestigating the trajectories of different a and b values such as 1 and 1/2. I have tried evaluating some of these and putting them in to your code. I am just wondering how to change the x0 values?

Comment: @FFerreira, please see the update re modification of the second method for your example.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

We can change `x0` by `Locator` and change `{a,b}` by `Slide2D`.

```
A[{a_, b_}] := {{2*b*a - a - b, b*a - a - b}, {2 (a + b - a*b), 
    2 (a + b) - a*b}};
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[NestList[A[ab] . # &, x0, 15], Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {{ab, {1, 1/2}, 
   Dynamic["{a,b}=" <> 
     ToString[ab, TraditionalForm]]}, {.8, .4}, {1.2, .6}}, 
 Dynamic["x0=" <> ToString[x0, TraditionalForm]], {{x0, {2, 1/3}}, 
  Locator}, ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

**Original**

```
A = {{Cos[π/3], -Sin[π/3] - .1}, {Sin[π/3], Cos[π/3]}};
x0 = {1, 1};
pts = NestList[A . # &, x0, 15];
ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or

```
A = {{Cos[π/3], -Sin[π/3] - .1}, {Sin[π/3], Cos[π/3]}};
x0 = {1, 1};
pts = NestList[A . # &, x0, 15];
Graphics[Arrow[Partition[pts, 2, 1]]]
```

[image]